# how to automatically divide one image to many small images?

Tags: slices

I have a big image which contains several small images. How to automatically slice them? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done Semi-automatically in GIMP (which is free and Open Source), just three simple steps. The only thing that isn't automatic is step 2: setting up the guides for the slices.

1. Do *Image > Zealous Crop*, this will remove all transparent spaces
2. Add 4 new guides using *Image > Guides > New guides by Percent*:  Two horizontal and two vertical guides each at 33.33% and 66.66%
3. Do *Image > Slice using Guides*